# How to bind a DataTable to a DropDownList using MVC RAZOR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

My Model returns a collection of DataTables as shown below.

How to bind a DataTable to a DropDownList using MVC RAZOR?

For each DataTable, I'd like to create a table row and a drop down list for it.

I tried the below code:

```
 foreach (DataTable dataTable in Model.ParameterDataSources)
      {
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Filter:
                </th>
                <td>                    
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlFilterDataSource", dataTable, "--Select One--") 
                </td>
            </tr>
      }
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549147/how-to-bind-datatable-to-html-dropdownlistfor-in-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: The link suggests a server side approach by creating a view specific model. you mean there is no good way to implement this using RAZOR as above?

Comment: try http://knockoutjs.com/ and be happy.

Answer (score 3):

A Simple solution is to convert your DataTable to DataView, and you should be good to go.

```
    //Controller Code
    ViewBag.Employees = new SelectList(objDt.AsDataView(), "id", "name");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<http://dotnetpools.com/Article/ArticleDetiail/?articleId=48&title=Binding%20Dropdownlist%20In%20MVC3%20Using%20C#t;>

## razor ##

    @Html.DropDownList("Country", new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text", Model.CountryList.SelectedValue), new { @id = "ddlist", @data_role = "none", style = "color: #fff; background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #333333; margin-left:3px; width:100%; height:20px;" })


## model ##

     public class somename
      {
       public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
      }
       public class Country
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

## Controller ##

       public ActionResult index()
        {
          List<Country> objcountry = new List<Country>();
          objcountry = GetCountryList();
          SelectList objlistofcountrytobind = new SelectList(objcountry, "ID", "Name", 0);
          model.CountryList = objlistofcountrytobind;       
          return View(model);
        }


      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Analyze(AnalyzeModels model)
       {
          List<Country> objcountry = new List<Country>();
          objcountry = GetCountryList();
          SelectList objlistofcountrytobind = new SelectList(objcountry, "ID", "Name", 0);
          model.CountryList = objlistofcountrytobind;
          return View(model);
       }
              **************************************************
## function for GetCountryList##
        public List<Country> GetCountryList()
        {
            DataTable reportDetailsTable = objCommon.GetDetails("tablename");

            List<Country> objcountrty = new List<Country>();
            int s = reportDetailsTable.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
            {
                string d1 = reportDetailsTable.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                string d2 = reportDetailsTable.Rows[i][10].ToString();
                objcountrty.Add(new Country { ID = d1, LName = d2 });
            }
            return objcountrty;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found all other approaches terribly confusing, so I did this in my view and seems to be working just fine. I am using vb.net

```
<select>
    @Code
        For Each row In Model.dataTable.Rows
            @<option>@row(0)</option>
        Next
    End Code
</select>
```