# How do I bind a datatable in a controller to a model via a repository and a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been working on a project for months and seem to always get stuck on binding the results so that I can pass them to a view where a user can bind the results to a model. I created a repository though I am unsure if it works but I will work on that when I figure this part out.

Well, my problem is the repository list, I can not figure out how to add the csvData columns to the DCResultsRepository list that is DCResults1, as I have understood is what I should do.
Beneath I have written the code of the first controller, the problem is located in this area:

```
for(int y = 0; y <csvData.Columns.Count; y++)
{
    string dc = csvData.Columns[y].ColumnName.ToString();
    var repository = new DCResultsRepository { 
        SelectedDCResults= dc
    };
    List<string> DCList DCResultsRepos.DCResults1 = new List<string>();
    var DC = DCResultsRepos.DCResults1(DCResultsRepos.SelectedDCResults.ToList());
}
DCResultsRepos.DCResults1.Contains(DCResultsRepos.SelectedDCResults);
```

This is the whole controller so that you can see what I am trying to do a bit more easily:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase file, string Delimiter, string Firstrow)
{
    DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(file.InputStream))
            {
                csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { Delimiter });
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = Firstrow == "true" ? true : false;
                string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                foreach (string column in colFields)
                {
                    DataColumn DataColumn = new DataColumn(column);
                    DataColumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                    csvData.Columns.Add(DataColumn);
                }
                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();

                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fieldData[i] == "")
                        {
                            fieldData[i] = null;
                        }
                    }
                    csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                }
                DataSet csvdata = new DataSet();
                csvdata.Tables.Add(csvData);
            }

            BFProj2.Models.OurColumns o = new Models.OurColumns();
            DCResultsRepository DCResultsRepos = new DCResultsRepository();
            o.DCResults = new List<string>();

            for(int y = 0; y <csvData.Columns.Count; y++)
            {
                string dc = csvData.Columns[y].ColumnName.ToString();
                var repository = new DCResultsRepository { 
                    SelectedDCResults= dc
                };
                //DCResultsRepos.DCResults1 = new List<string>();
                List<string> DCList DCResultsRepos.DCResults1 = new List<string>();
                var DC = DCResultsRepos.DCResults1(DCResultsRepos.SelectedDCResults.ToList());
            }
            DCResultsRepos.DCResults1.Contains(DCResultsRepos.SelectedDCResults);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //return View("Error"+ ex.GetType().ToString());
        }
        Ska få med DCResults1 listan med csvData i.
    }
    return View();
}
```

I am unsure how the repository should be thought I will work on that after I have figured out what I can do to bind csvData and repository so that I can pass it on to a get actionresult. But if it is important for answering the question the repository looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using BFProj2.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace BFProj2
{
    public class DCResultsRepository
    {
        public List<string> DCResults1 { get; set; }

        public string SelectedDCResults { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also this is another question that I have asked a short while back that I have been trying to use when figuring out how to let the user bind the csvData results to a model:  [How do I bind a datatable to model and then to a dropdownlist in mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920942/how-do-i-bind-a-datatable-to-model-and-then-to-a-dropdownlist-in-mvc)

Though I am still confused. And I have looked at a lot of similar questions and read up about it. But there are always these differences that makes it seem that what I am trying to do to be impossible.

How am I supposed to bind the csvData columns to a model through a repository?

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that your controller seems clogged with logic that shouldn't be in the controller. This makes reading your own code harder, as well as writing the same basic operations, because it contains all kinds of operations that do not make sense when writing a controller method.  The single responsibility principle states that every class should have a single responsibility, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility. The controllers responsibility is to mediate between the models and the view, not to parse data from files.

I would recommend reading the implementing of [repository and uow patterns](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). Once these are in place you could even go further by [seperating queries and commands](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92), in which the data is bound to models by (data/query)Handlers. This is all done is seperate files so that your controller methods are clean and do what they are supposed to do.

Comment: I tried to not have this in the controller to begin with, but the code did not work on normal classes. And I can not place the rows and columns lying in the csvData Datatable on a model as it has custom rows in each file that is placed in it and so the user has to pick if possible both what model to place it in and what row. Both of these explanatory links take for granted that I know what columns are in the file I am trying to bind, but I can not take that for granted and so the user has to bind the model to the columns and rows themselves before I can do more to it.

Comment: @E.A.O.S: is this an actual use-case or a consequence of not knowing how to bind to the right model, and because of that, making it the users' problem?

Comment: This is an actual use-case. The user is supposed to post a file in csv format and the file should be able to be posted to any table/tables in the database as they want it. There is a need to make it as dynamic as possible for the user.

Comment: The users want to handle where it goes and exactly what information is added from the file and so I have to make views where they can pick from these options before it is added to the database per their request. And so the model and repository need to reflect this.