# JSON Arrays for multiple values in ASP.NET API

Tags: sql, asp.net, json, sql-server, api

I've built a simple API for querying a local SQL database (for a database course). I'm using Postman to test my endpoints, but the results I'm getting aren't formatted the way I'd like.  For example, in this query I ask my database for data about 1 person but it's returning all the unique sets.

[image: The json that I'm outputting]

What I would like is something like this (multivalues in a list):

[image: the json I want]

My API is calling a stored procedure that's pretty lengthy, but this is the select statement at the end (a lengthy inner join):

```
        SELECT DISTINCT specializationType, memberSince, teamName, E.meetingsAttended, lifetimeScore
        FROM participants AS A
        INNER JOIN
        ONTEAM AS B
        ON A.participantKey = B.participantKey
        INNER JOIN
        MEMBERSHIP AS C
        ON A.participantKey = C.participantKey
        INNER JOIN
        SPECIALIZATIONPART AS D
        ON A.participantKey = D.participantKey
        INNER JOIN
        MEETINGCOUNT as E
        ON A.participantKey = E.participantKey;
```

The endpoint that's calling this is:

```
// GET api/InfoSecDB/adminSelectsParticipant
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("adminSelectsParticipant")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> adminSelectsParticipant([FromBody] JObject data)
        {
            string pName = (string)data["pName"];
            List<string> distinctSpecializations = new List<string>();
            List<string> allTeams = new List<string>();

            List<string> myP = new List<string>();
            DatabaseModel dbm = new DatabaseModel();
            DataTable dt = dbm.adminSelectsParticipant(pName);

            return Ok(dt);
        }
```

I'm not sure if this something that's supposed to be done by the stored procedure or the API endpoint. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd recommend writing LINQ query and handle results there. And at the end, use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` together with `JsonProperty` attribute from `Newtonsoft` library to "JSONize" and send response.

Answer (score 0):

Something you may want to do for this is set up a Model with each of the fields that you want to display. You can then loop through your DataTable and assign it to your model, then return your model in the way you want with your second image above.

Here is something that I found, it should be similar to what you want:
[How do I bind a datatable to model and then to a dropdownlist in mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920942/how-do-i-bind-a-datatable-to-model-and-then-to-a-dropdownlist-in-mvc)

Your model would look something like this:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<string> SpecializationType { get; set; }
    public DateTime MemberSince { get; set; }
    public List<string> TeamName { get; set; }
    public int MeetingsAttended { get; set; }
    public int LifetimeScore { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could do var model = new List(); and assign your DataTable values to it.